# What is the difference between a dedicated and colocated cache? How would a colocated cache work?

Tags: caching, architecture, distributed-system

According to [the following video](https://youtu.be/iuqZvajTOyA?t=647), a dedicated cache is a cache process hosted on a separate server while a colocated cache is a cache process hosted directly on the service hosts. Is that the standard definition? I can not find any more on this topic online.

In the colocated cache scenario would the service always reference the cache that is on this specific host or would it need to query other hosts as well? Is it possible to route requests to only hosts that have a colocated cache for that partition of data then in order to avoid the extra network hop to a cache server that would be needed to retrieve data in the dedicated cache host scenario?

Answer (score 0):

In a colocated cache querying only the service instance hosting the data can be accomplished by sharding the data (typically by some key).  Given a key, a requestor can resolve which shard owns the data, then resolve which instance owns the shard and direct the request at that instance.  As long as everyone agrees on both levels of ownership, this works really well.  It's also possible to have each instance of the service be able to forward requests so that even if a request gets misdirected it will with some likelihood eventually reach the correct instance.

[Adya (2019)](https://research.google/pubs/pub48030/) describes the broad approach, calling it a LInK store, which can take the approach of embedding the cache into actual service (which doesn't even require local interprocess communication).  When this is done, there's basically no line between your service and the cache: the service *is* the cache and databases/object stores only exist to allow cold data to be evicted and to provide durability.  One benefit of this approach is that your database/object store in the sunny day case mostly handles writes, and it ends up having a lot of mechanical sympathy to CQRS.

I personally have had a lot of success using Akka to implement services following this approach (Akka Cluster manages cluster membership and failure detection, Akka Cluster Sharding handles shard distribution and resolution, and Akka Persistence provides durability).